# Is it possible to get the address of a place while clicking on map and store it in database..and show a marker on that place

Tags: google-maps

I have a map using api v3...i need when someone click on map the location of clicked place should be saved in the database and the marker should be added on the map.

Comment: Well, what does the API documentation offer?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the Google Maps documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

What you are looking for is the [`click` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events), binded to the map. Here's an example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alestanis really worked for me i was lost a bit click event worked The event.latLng is object which contains the variable latitude and longitude like this var myLatitude = position.lat(); 
 var myLongitude = position.lng();